# How to process the filename from multiple directory by Perl?

Tags: perl

I am using the Perl to phase the multiple .txt files from different multiple directories.

I have folders: `A_1`, `A_2`, `A_3`, ...
The file lists in `A_1` folder is:
 
`V_3_C_1.txt`, `V_3_C_2.txt`, ...,`V_3_C_38.txt`, and
 
`V_1_C_1.txt`, `V_1_C_2.txt`, ...,`V_1_C_38.txt`.
for some reasons, the files in the `A_1` folder can be grouped into `V_3` and `V_1`

The file lists in `A_2` folder is:
 
`V_4_C_1.txt`, `V_4_C_2.txt`, ...,`V_4_C_38.txt`, and
 
`V_1_C_1.txt`, `V_1_C_2.txt`, ...,`V_1_C_38.txt`.
 the files in the `A_2` folder can be grouped into `V_4` and `V_1`

I going to run a system (java program) by Perl. The first thing that I am going to extract the part of filename. 
My Codes is here:

```
my % seen;
my @dups;
my @unqie;

my $file_list = '/home/V/Documents/A_1';
opendir (DIR, $file_list) or die "Could not open $file_list\n";  
my @vcf_files = grep (/\.txt$/, readdir DIR);  

for my $line (@vcf_files) {
    my @vcf_index = split ('_' , $line);
    my @dups = grep ++$seen{$_} ==2, $vcf_index[1]; #get the unique values, for example in `A_1` folder, I try to extract 3 and 1 from `V_3` and `V_1  `  
    push @unqie, @dups; #push into array for next steps. 

    for (my $i=1; $i <=38; $i++) {
        my @external_command = (
            "java",
            "-jar",
            "/home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar",
            "gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V_".$unqie[0]."_C_".$i."\.txt",
            "out = .............."
        );
        my @external_command_1 = (
            "java",
            "-jar",
            "/home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar",
            "gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V_".$unqie[1]."_C_".$i."\.txt",  
            "out = .............. "
        );

        my $out = system(@external_command);
        my $out_1 = system(@external_command_1);
        # ....
    }
}
```

For this code, the java program run well.
However, when I add a loop for this code, I want to process a folder one by one: open `A_1` then run java, finish. Open `A_2` then run java, finish...open `A_3`, ........

```
for (my $j=1; $j<=2; $j++) {
    my $file_list = '/home/v/Documents/A_' . $j;
    opendir (DIR, $file_list) or die "Could not open $file_list\n";

    my @vcf_files = grep (/\.txt$/, readdir DIR);
    for my $line (@vcf_files) {
        my @vcf_index = split ('_' , $line);
        my @dups = grep ++$seen{$_} ==2, $vcf_index[1];
        push @unqie, @dups;

        for (my $i=1; $i <=38; $i++) {
            my @external_command = (
                "java",
                "-jar",
                "/home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar",
                "gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.$j/V_" . $unqie[0] . "_C_".$i."\.txt",  
                "out = .............."
            );
            my @external_command_1 = (
                "java",
                "-jar",
                "/home/victor/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar",
                "gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.$j/V_".$unqie[1]."_C_".$i."\.txt",  
                "out = .............."
            );

            my $out = system(@external_command);
            my $out_1 = system(@external_command_1);
        }
    }
}
```

I can not get the results that I want. I am using print to check. I think I know something wrong at file names part but I can not solve it.

Can anyone help me to figure it out? Thanks

Comment: Even the syntax highlighting here shows the unclosed single quoted string.

Comment: Sorry, that I still don't know how to fix.

Comment: @Victor.H: There's an "edit" link just under your question. And while you're there, please fix the indentation too.

Comment: Where do you declare the hash `%seen`  and the array `@unqie` ? Also, I think you have one too many `for` loops. Git rid of one of the two innermost ones.

Answer (score 2):

A good approach to debug stuff like this is to not run the programs, but to print out the command line to see what is going to be run.

That is, replace these lines:

```
my $out = system(@external_command);
my $out_1 = system(@external_command_1);
```

with these:

```
print "@external_command\n";
print "@external_command_1\n";
```

(Incidentally, it looks like there's a misunderstanding in your original code there - `system()` returns the process exit code, not the output.)

Running that, your first code gives me output like this:

```
java -jar /home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V__C_1.txt out = ..............
java -jar /home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V__C_1.txt out = ..............
java -jar /home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V__C_2.txt out = ..............
java -jar /home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_1/V__C_2.txt out = ..............
```

That doesn't look right to me. See you have things like `V__C_1.txt`. That looks like it's missing a value between the two underscores. It comes from this code:

```
"gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.$j/V_".$unqie[0]."_C_".$i."\.txt"
```

And this code:

```
"gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.$j/V_".$unqie[1]."_C_".$i."\.txt"
```

So it looks like `@unqie` never gets any data in it. And that means that `@dup` never gets any data in it either.

Running your second program gives output like this:

```
java -jar /home/V/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.1/V__C_1.txt out = ..............
java -jar /home/victor/Documents/beagle.03Jul19.b33.jar gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.1/V__C_1.txt out = ..............
```

That has the same problem as the first version (presumably caused by the same thing) but it also has this - `A_.1`. That comes from this code:

```
"gt=/home/V/Documents/A_.$j/V_" . $unqie[0] . "_C_".$i."\.txt",
```

Specificially, from `A_.$j`. I think you meant that dot as the concatenation operator, but as it's inside a quoted string, it is just interpreted as a dot. It's easy to fix by just removing the dot.

It's hard to be much more help as I'm not really clear what you're trying to do and variables like `%seen` and `@unqie` just spring into existence without explanation. But here are some other tips.

- Add `use strict` and `use warnings`. And fix the problems they will reveal.
- `for (my $j=1; $j<=2; $j++)` is probably clearer written as `for my $i (1 .. 2)`
- Use a lexical variable for directory handles (`opendir my $dir_h, $file_list` and `readdir $dir_h`)
- The first argument to `split` is a regex (`split /_/, $line`)
- Variables are expanded in double-quoted strings

If you expand on what you're trying to do, then we can probably be more help.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I can get the values for $unqie[0] and $unqie[1]. For the first loop, the values is 3 and 1. But when I run the second loop, the ideal result should be 4 and 1. I check the @unqie, the values is 3, 1 and 4. I have no ideal how to get 4 and 1 in the $unqie[0] and $unqie[1] or (replace) at the second loop.

Comment: @Victor.H: *I can get the values for $unqie[0] and $unqie[1]* I don't know what that means. Your code doesn't set those values. If you're getting values in that array then either your code or your environment is not what you have told us.